# How can I install python packages using spyder?

Tags: python, pandas, installation

I feel like this should be an easy enough process -- I'm typing

```
pip install pandas
```

into the console and it tells me "Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
'C:\Users\Chuck' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I try

```
conda install pandas
```

and get the same result.

I open up consoles > Restart Kernel and re-launch it; same result.

I try the same commands using jupyter Notebook, same response.

I've also tried going through the command prompt directly with the same commands, this way I get

"Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python27\python.exe"  "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe" install pandas'"

I'm not really sure what's wrong here, can someone please advise? I've been able to install packages in the past and I'm not sure what's going wrong now.